# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mysqldb'

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am running `Python 3.7.4`. This is the only version installed on my machine. I pip installed flask-mysqldb. But, I can't import flask_mysqldb.

I have tried many options but nothing worked for,

```
C:\sys\Flask\dev\projects\test\a006_myflaskapp>pip3 install flask-mysqldb
Requirement already satisfied: flask-mysqldb in c:\users\anild\appdata\local\programs\python\lib\site-packages (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in c:\users\anild\appdata\local\programs\python\lib\site-packages (from flask-mysqldb) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in c:\users\anild\appdata\local\programs\python\lib\site-packages (from flask-mysqldb) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in c:\users\anild\appdata\local\programs\python\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in c:\users\anild\appdata\local\programs\python\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (2.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\users\anild\appdata\local\programs\python\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in c:\users\anild\appdata\local\programs\python\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (0.15.5)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\anild\appdata\local\programs\python\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (1.1.1)

C:\sys\Flask\dev\projects\test\a006_myflaskapp>python
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask_mysqldb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mysqldb'
>>>
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your import is `import flask_mysqldb` which looks incorrect

The correct import syntax is `from flask_mysqldb import MySQL`

Referenced here: https://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose the correct interpreter of python to solve the issue. if you are using vscode make sure you choose the correct version of python in right down section of your vscode
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmBfw.png)

if you are using a virtual environment make sure you choose the python interpreter inside the virtual environment instead of the global python interpreter. you can click on the interpreter in right down section and select + Enter interpreter path on the top and browse to the folder where you create the virtual environment and select the python.exe file